# Is there a way to make my form inputs already filled with some data?

Tags: reactjs

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className="mb-4">
            <label
              htmlFor="title"
              className="block text-gray-700 font-bold mb-2"
            >
              Title
            </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="title"
              name="title"
              className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          {/* author */}

          <div className="mb-4">
            <label
              htmlFor="author"
              className="block text-gray-700 font-bold mb-2"
            >
              Author
            </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="author"
              name="author"
              className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </div>

          {/* language */}
          <div className="mb-4">
            <label
              htmlFor="language"
              className="block text-gray-700 font-bold mb-2"
            >
              Language
            </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="language"
              name="language"
              className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </div>

          {/* year_of_prod */}

          <div className="mb-4">
            <label
              htmlFor="year_of_prod"
              className="block text-gray-700 font-bold mb-2"
            >
              Year of production
            </label>
            <input
              type="number"
              id="year_of_prod"
              name="year_of_prod"
              className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </div>

          {/* publisher */}

          <div className="mb-4">
            <label
              htmlFor="publisher"
              className="block text-gray-700 font-bold mb-2"
            >
              Publisher
            </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="publisher"
              name="publisher"
              className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </div>

          {/* subjects */}

          <div className="mb-4">
            <label
              htmlFor="subjects"
              className="block text-gray-700 font-bold mb-2"
            >
              Subjects
            </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="subjects"
              name="subjects"
              className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </div>

          {/* no_of_pages */}

          <div className="mb-4">
            <label
              htmlFor="no_of_pages"
              className="block text-gray-700 font-bold mb-2"
            >
              Number of pages
            </label>
            <input
              type="number"
              id="no_of_pages"
              name="no_of_pages"
              className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </div>

          {/* price */}

          <div className="mb-4">
            <label
              htmlFor="price"
              className="block text-gray-700 font-bold mb-2"
            >
              Price
            </label>
            <input
              type="number"
              id="price"
              name="price"
              className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </div>

          {/* rack */}

          <div className="mb-4">
            <label
              htmlFor="rack"
              className="block text-gray-700 font-bold mb-2"
            >
              Rack
            </label>
            <input
              type="number"
              id="rack"
              name="rack"
              className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </div>

          {/* image */}

          <div className="mb-4">
            <label
              htmlFor="image"
              className="block text-gray-700 font-bold mb-2"
            >
              Image
            </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="image"
              name="image"
              className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </div>

          {/* isbn */}
          <div className="mb-4">
            <label
              htmlFor="isbn"
              className="block text-gray-700 font-bold mb-2"
            >
              ISBN
            </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="isbn"
              name="isbn"
              className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="mb-4">
            <button
              type="submit"
              className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
            >
              Add Book
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
```

this is part of the code written in react and tailwind. My idea is when the user is clicking on a book this form will appear with some filled data of the selected book and then the user can change or update the book info by changing some of the "prefilled data". The problem is that I don't know how make the inputs of a form already filled.

I tried a lot using the attribute value but didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put a `value={someState}` in the input, or `defauleValue={someState}`
like this

```
<input
type="text"
id="language"
name="language"
className="your classes"
onChange={handleChange}
value={someState}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

inputs can receive a "defaultValue" attribute.  this will behave as described: the form inputs will start with values that can be changed by the user.

example:

```
<input
    name="author"
    defaultValue="Ray Bradbury"
    id="author"
    onChange="handleChange"
/>
```

react doc link:
https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/input#providing-an-initial-value-for-an-input

you could alternatively use "controlled" inputs by using the value attribute and useState hook, but that may not be exactly what you're looking for in this instance since it brings in more state management.